# How to get Hudson CI to check out CVS projects over SSH?

Tags: ssh, cvs, hudson

I have my Hudson CI server setup. I have a CVS repo that I can only checkout stuff via ssh. But I see no way to convince Hudson to check out via ssh. I tried all sorts of options when supplying my connection string.

Has anyone done this? I gotta think it has been done.

Comment: Can you list some of the connection strings that didn't work ?

Comment: Did you try it manually from the machine that Hudson is running on? Preferably under the same user account that Hudson uses. Did it work? Also, have a look at the following page: http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-cvs.php

Comment: It works manually, both under my own account and root (on the hudson server). I even use the same command that is produced in the hudson build. I even set it up so that both those accounts can checkout with out passwords by putting my public key on the cvs server.

The connection strings I used are the typical:

<username>@<host>:<path>

I pulled it straight from my CVS_HOME. I experimented using the :ext: protocol stuff at the beginning. 

I guess I'm not sure what Hudson will run as. Will it be the tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

If I still remember CVS, I thought you have to set CVS_RSH environment variable to ssh. I suspect you need to set this so that your Tomcat process gets this value inherited.

You can check Hudson system information to see exactly what environment variables the JVM is seeing (and passes along to the build.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up an article that tackles this you can find it here:
http://www.openscope.net/2011/01/03/configure-ssh-authorized-keys-for-cvs-access/

Essentially you want to set up passphraseless ssh keys for your build user. This will allow authentication to occur without the need to work out some kind of way to key in your password.

<edit> i.e. Essentially the standard .ssh key client & server install/exchange.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Key_management

for the jenkins user account:

- install user key (public & private part) in ~/.ssh (generate it fresh or use existing user key)

on cvs server:

- install user key (public part) in ~/.ssh
- add to authorized_keys

back on jenkins user account:

- access cvs from command-line as jenkins user and accept remote host key (to known_hosts)
  *** note any time remote server changes key/ip you will need to manually access cvs and accept key again ***

</edit>

There's another way to do it but you have to manually log from the build machine to your cvs server and keep the ssh session open so hudson/jenkins can piggyback the connection. Seemed kinda pointless to me though since you want your CI server to be as hands off as possible.